# Passing unknown struct to function

Tags: c++, struct

Is it possible to pass an unknown struct to a function and iterate through its elements? If yes, what is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: What you are asking for is called reflection, and C++ does not yet support that. There are libraries you can use to give you something similar though, but they required you manually register the members of all the types you want to participate in the reflection.

Comment: This is a two-part question with a two-part answer: 1) You can pass an "unknown" struct via polymorphism or templates. 2) You can iterate through its elements with the help of a library like Boost.Fusion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335170/accessing-members-in-a-c-struct-both-dynamically-and-statically for this second point.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! This already helped much. Now I know what to look for.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ solution is to pass a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), not a `struct`. You can then call `std::get<I>(std::tuple)` with I running from 0 to `std::tuple_size`